# Is it ok to ask Rails 4 questions yet?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to begin developing beta applications with Rails 4 to get ahead of the curve. I've found that I could start asking a number of questions about migrating over to 4, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask Rails 4 questions yet on Stack Overflow since the newest edge Rails is still only at 4.0.0.beta.

Is it appropriate to ask Rails 4 questions on Stack Overflow? If not, where should I be asking these questions?

Comment: I'd say go for it. You might have to wait a while before you get answers, though.

Comment: Are more than 10 other people using the language? Yes? Then yes it's okay to ask questions already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bring 'em on!  Seriously!  If you're reviewing beta software, then you're more than likely *not* a help vampire. You're most likely a pioneer who is venturing into heavy, unknown territory to pave the way for the rest of us.

I'd expect the questions to be pretty in-depth, technical questions, with code examples, things you've tried, what error messages you're encountering, and a description of what you're trying to do. Of course, this is expected with *any* Stack Overflow question. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

That would absolutely be acceptable.

There's no rule on Stack Overflow that limits questions to technologies that are mature and fully implemented. There are even [a few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) on the next version of ECMAScript (JavaScript), and that's not even finalized yet.